# How to exclude specific jars when using gradle in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I think there is a function to exculde from the pop-up menu by right-clicking on the screen below.

[image]

And I added my own build.gradle like below, but the dependency I want is not removed.

```
dependencies {
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.5.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
    }
....
....
}
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you missed "log4j" at the end of group name: "exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j' "